# Converting clock radio from 60 hz to 50 hz

Tags: power, ac, frequency

I have an old clock radio that works fine, except for one detail. The clock is made for 60 hz mains but I would like to use it in a country where 50 hz is the standard. As the clock directly relies on the mains frequency to keep track of time, it slows down when used with 50 hz mains power, making it useless as a clock.

Is it likely that it is possible to modify the clock to work with 50 hz mains power? The clock radio is a Panasonic RC-6030. I have not been able to dig up schematics for it.

Comment: You should open it and take some pictures, but I think such a modification is not simple, nor it is worth the time/effort/money, unless you like the radio for a particular motivation and/or you want to mess with it a bit.

Comment: If it uses the popular LM8560 chip then you can use pin 26 to select 50Hz operation.

Comment: You may need to change the primary clock chip. It would probably be cheaper and easier to get a new clock.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. It's a mechanical flip-digit clock, which means it uses a synchronous motor to operate the clock mechanism. The gear train that selects 50 Hz vs. 60 Hz operation is sealed inside the motor, so you have to replace the entire motor in order to change it. It just isn't worth the effort or expense.